# What's another way to write "and on top of that"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

What is a more professional and academic way to write "and on top of that"?

> The man has excellent qualifications "and top of that" he has a position on the board.

Comment: In that sentence I'd write... _excellent qualifications as well as a position on the board_. If there are longer, complete sentences before and you want to finish off with important information: _Moreover, he holds a position on the board_.

Comment: in addition, additionally, as well, what's more, furthermore, moreover, also, to boot, likewise

Comment: too top it all off ...

Answer (score 1):

**crowned**  [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/crown)

> Be the triumphant culmination of (an effort or endeavour, especially a
>   prolonged one. ‘years of struggle were crowned by a state visit to
>   Paris’

Use in your sentence:
The man has excellent qualifications, **crowned** by a position on the board ... or crowned by his position on the board.

another definition: 
Crowned [Amer Dict Eng Lan](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/crowned)

> CROWNED, participle passive Invested with a crown, or with regal power
>   and dignity; **honored**; **dignified**; rewarded with a crown,
>   wreath, garland or **distinction**; recompensed; terminated;
>   completed; perfected.

Answer (score 1):

'In addition to' and 'furthermore' can fit here.

The man has a position on the board **in addition to** his excellent qualifications.

Or

The man has excellent qualifications. **Furthermore**, he has a position on the board.

Answer (score 0):

Complemented" "Something that fills up, completes or makes perfect." MW

The man has excellent qualifications, complemented by a position on the board.